# Android No view found for ID in FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can someone more familiar with `Fragment` details that I am tell what is causing this error? It is occurring for a number of users, but I don't have any info on exactly what they're doing when it occurs and I am unable to recreate anything on my own device.

Here is the stack trace. It appears to be happening when the fragment is being popped from the backstack -- is this correct? Any other clues?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c006b for fragment AncestorNavFrag
{41324df0 #2 id=0x7f0c006b ancest_nav}
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:864)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:697)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1511)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$4.run(FragmentManager.java:473)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id