# Error message "No view found" when creating fragment in Android

Tags: android, fragment

I'm starting to learn Android and am having a problem when creating fragments. I've tried creating a fragment in code in just about every way every tutorial specifies but every time I do the program immediately crashes and I get a log error "no view found for [id of fragment for container]".

The activity I create the fragment from is:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    FragmentTestActivity activity = new FragmentTestActivity();
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, activity);
    ft.commit();
}


}
```

The fragment itself if

```
public class FragmentTestActivity extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, parent, false);
    return vw;
}
}
```

And the layout of the fragment is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container" >


</FrameLayout>
```

It doesn't do anything useful at the moment, I just want to see if I can make a fragment before moving on to do anything useful, but every time I try the program crashes.

Comment: and the layout for activity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Fragment no view found for ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id)

Answer (score 1):

`activity_main.xml` must have a `FrameLayout` with  id `fragment_container`.

Your `FrameLayout` is the container. You add the the fragment to the `FrameLayout`. Your fragment is hosted by a activity.

Also i don't think you require a FrameLayout in fragment layout. You can have other views for fragment layout.

Comment: Isn't the id passed to the fragment transaction that of the fragment's container?

Comment: @Ghost no. its not. Try the suggestion in my post and it should work

Comment: Thanks, it does. I must have misread something somewhere. I've changed the container to the main layout and it does indeed work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Raghunandan is it must be FrameLayout? or can be LinearLayout, RelativeLayout like that?

Comment: it can be a view group

Answer (score 0):

```
ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, activity);
```

In this `fragment_container` needs to be in activity layout not fragment layout.

Answer (score 0):

By doing this

```
ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, activity);
```

you are trying to add your Fragment to a View inside the MainActivity that has an id of `R.id.fragment_container`. Since `fragment_container` if part of your Fragment's layout and not part of your MainActivity's layout, it causes your error.

Make sure you have a ViewGroup that has the id `R.id.fragment_container` inside your MainActivity layout and rename the main ViewGroup's id inside your Fragment layout.