# How to Do Transaction of framents from one to another

Tags: android, transactions, fragment

I want to transact from one fragment to another... below given is my snippet...

I want transaction on button click...

```
    public class Main extends Fragment {
 // final View rootView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
     Button camera=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
     camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.layout.main, new CameraActivity());
        ft.commit();
        }
     });

    return rootView;

    }
```

so please Assist me in solving this...

```
[1]<--->[2]<--->[3]<--->[4]<--->[5]
```

where []=fragments...

```
[1]- has buttons a,b,c,d,e
How to move from 1 to 3 OnClick of c ...
```

Here is the Camera Activity

```
 public class CameraActivity  extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
    }
```

Comment: you are getting any error ?

Comment: Error in log is-

Note-CameraActivity is a Class File which Extends Fragemnt...

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030004 (com.example.banku:layout/main) for fragment CameraActivity{41387b48 #2 id=0x7f030004}

Comment: can you please post camera activity code?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id

Comment: @Mehul i just simply want to launch new class file when click on button (As like Intent)

Comment: Have you check the link for your error ?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id

Comment: Yeah But i got myself More Confused...

Comment: are you applying proper layout file in cameraActivity class ?

Comment: yeah... i am applying.... @MehulRanpara

Comment: have you figured this out yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all this cant be activity

```
 ft.replace(R.layout.main, new CameraActivity());
```

it has to be fragment
put something like this in your onclick listener in FirstFragment:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", value); //if you want to pass parameter to second fragment
SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

than in your SecondFragment onclick listener:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", value); //if you want to pass parameter to second fragment
ThirdFragment fragment = new ThirdFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

and so on ...

method `addToBackStack(null)` is providing you back as simple as that. You could also pass some tag in that method if you need it, but I think from question you want be needing it.

Also if you need to start `Activity` than dont use this method, use `Intent` instead.

hope it helps

Comment: CameraActivity is a class file  not Activity ...

and i want to simply go to other class (Like Intent in Activity)

Comment: first of all, if CameraActivity extends Fragment than please call it CameraFragment, it is a lot more natural... also, answer I provide you works :)