# Error in Fragment Back Stack in My code

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like implement back stack in my code in that,|1|,|2|,|3|,|4| & |5| these are Fragment button in one fragment ,In these fragment all are replace one frame in one activity. 
I have used addToBackStack() method. These working properly when |1|-->|1|a --> b--> c then c-->b-->a|1| but when I click on |1|-->|1|a --> b--> c-->|2| then it give error .
Any other method to handle back key.

My Main Activity class code is,

```
package com.PersianBeauty;

import com.Fragment.Classes.*;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.PersianBeauty.Adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.Sliding.Model.NavDrawerItem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    int defaul=4;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    View customView;
  TextView txt_title;
    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();  
        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable();
        colorDrawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("#f059a5"));
        actionBar.setTitle("Pearsian Beauty Awards ");
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.contestant_img);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        //customView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar_view, null);
        //actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
        //txt_title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        //set Color to action bar 



        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Winners
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0,-1)));
        // Contactus
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // About us
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // About us
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // About us
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // About us
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) 
            {
                displayView(position);
            }
        });


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.btn_option, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
                ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) 
            {   
                //txt_title.setText(mTitle);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {

                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) 
        {  

            // on first time display view for first nav item
            HomeFragment    fragment = new HomeFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        }

    }




    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    /*
    private  class SlidingMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) 
        {
            displayView(position);
        }

    }*/


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) 
    {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) 
        {

        case 0:
            fragment = new Context_Winner_Fragment();
            getActionBar().setTitle("Winners");
            getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.winner);

            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Context_AboutUs_Fragment();
            getActionBar().setTitle("About Us");
            getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.about_us);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Context_ContactUs_Fragment();
            getActionBar().setTitle("Contact Us");
            getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.contact_us);
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Context_Facebook_Fragment();
            getActionBar().setTitle("Facebook");
            getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.contact_us);
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Context_Twitter_Fragment();
            getActionBar().setTitle("Twitter");
            getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.contact_us);
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new Context_Share_Fragment();
            getActionBar().setTitle("Share");
            getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.contact_us);
            break;



        default:

            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            if(fragment instanceof HomeFragment)
            {
                actionBar.setCustomView(customView);}
            else
            {   

                setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) 
    {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Fragment class is,

```
 package com.Fragment.Classes;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.PersianBeauty.R;
import com.Sliding.Model.ModelListItem;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener
{
    ListView list_model;
    View rootView;
    int model_images[]={R.drawable.karina,R.drawable.karina,R.drawable.karina,R.drawable.karina};
    ArrayList<ModelListItem> modelList;
    ModelListItem modelItem;
    Button btn_Vote,btn_Gallary,btn_Events,btn_Sponsers,btn_Model;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   


        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_home,container, false);

        setUI();
        eventClick();

        if(savedInstanceState==null)
        {   
            setView(2);
            getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Persian Beaty Awards");
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    private void eventClick() 
    {
        btn_Vote.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_Gallary.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_Events.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_Sponsers.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_Model.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void setUI() 
    {
        btn_Vote=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_lin_vote);
        btn_Gallary=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_lin_gallary);
        btn_Events=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_lin_events);
        btn_Model=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_lin_models);
        btn_Sponsers=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_lin_sponsers);

    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {  
    int id=v.getId();
    switch(id)
    {

    case R.id.btn_lin_vote :

        setView(1);

        break;

    case R.id.btn_lin_models :

        setView(2);

        break;
    case R.id.btn_lin_sponsers :

        setView(3);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_lin_events :

        setView(4);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_lin_gallary :

        setView(5);
        break;
    }

    }

    private void setView(int id)
    {
         Fragment fragment = null;
        switch(id)
        {
        case 2 :
            fragment = new ModelsFragment();

            break;
        case 4 :
            fragment = new EventsFragment();

            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new SponsersFragment();

            break;
        case 5 :
            fragment = new GallaryFragment();

            break;
        case 1 :
            fragment = new VoteFragment();

            break;

        }
        if (fragment != null)
        {
           fragmentManagerSet(fragment);
        }

    }

    public void fragmentManagerSet(Fragment fragment) 
    {

          FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
          for(int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()-2; i++) 
           {    
               fragmentManager.popBackStack();
           }
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fram_home, fragment).addToBackStack("Home Fragment").commit();

    }
```

it givesfollowing error

```
02-17 10:24:24.160: E/FragmentManager(7019): No view found for id 0x7f0a0058 (com.PersianBeauty:id/frame_models_list_detail) for fragment Frag_All_ModelList{40edee38 #2 id=0x7f0a0058}
02-17 10:24:24.160: E/FragmentManager(7019): Activity state:
02-17 10:24:24.160: E/FragmentManager(7019):   Local Activity 40cec5f0 State:
02-17 10:24:24.170: E/FragmentManager(7019):     mResumed=true mStopped=false mFinished=false
02-17 10:24:24.170: E/FragmentManager(7019):     mLoadersStarted=true
02-17 10:24:24.170: E/FragmentManager(7019):     mChangingConfigurations=false
02-17 10:24:24.170: E/FragmentManager(7019):     mCurrentConfig={1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw320dp w320dp h508dp 240dpi nrml long port finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h s.6}
02-17 10:24:24.170: E/FragmentManager(7019):   Active Fragments in 40cec708:
02-17 10:24:24.180: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #0: HomeFragment{40cdedf0 #0 id=0x7f0a0001}
02-17 10:24:24.200: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mFragmentId=#7f0a0001 mContainerId=#7f0a0001 mTag=null
02-17 10:24:24.200: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mState=5 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
02-17 10:24:24.200: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=true mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
02-17 10:24:24.200: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
02-17 10:24:24.210: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
02-17 10:24:24.210: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{40cec708 in MainActivity{40cec5f0}}
02-17 10:24:24.220: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mActivity=com.PersianBeauty.MainActivity@40cec5f0
02-17 10:24:24.220: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mContainer=android.widget.FrameLayout{40d10140 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-480,690 #7f0a0001 app:id/frame_container}
02-17 10:24:24.220: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mView=android.widget.LinearLayout{40d0c5a0 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-480,690 #7f0a000c app:id/lin_lay_home}
02-17 10:24:24.220: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #1: ModelsFragment{40ce06f0 #1 id=0x7f0a000d}
02-17 10:24:24.220: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mFragmentId=#7f0a000d mContainerId=#7f0a000d mTag=null
02-17 10:24:24.220: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mState=1 mIndex=1 mWho=android:fragment:1 mBackStackNesting=2
02-17 10:24:24.230: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mAdded=false mRemoving=true mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
02-17 10:24:24.230: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
02-17 10:24:24.230: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
02-17 10:24:24.230: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{40cec708 in MainActivity{40cec5f0}}
02-17 10:24:24.230: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mActivity=com.PersianBeauty.MainActivity@40cec5f0
02-17 10:24:24.230: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mSavedViewState=android.util.SparseArray@40edf110
02-17 10:24:24.240: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #2: Frag_All_ModelList{40edee38 #2 id=0x7f0a0058}
02-17 10:24:24.240: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mFragmentId=#7f0a0058 mContainerId=#7f0a0058 mTag=null
02-17 10:24:24.240: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mState=0 mIndex=2 mWho=android:fragment:2 mBackStackNesting=0
02-17 10:24:24.240: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
02-17 10:24:24.240: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
02-17 10:24:24.250: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
02-17 10:24:24.250: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{40cec708 in MainActivity{40cec5f0}}
02-17 10:24:24.250: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mActivity=com.PersianBeauty.MainActivity@40cec5f0
02-17 10:24:24.260: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #3: VoteFragment{40edc820 #3 id=0x7f0a000d}
02-17 10:24:24.260: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mFragmentId=#7f0a000d mContainerId=#7f0a000d mTag=null
02-17 10:24:24.260: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mState=5 mIndex=3 mWho=android:fragment:3 mBackStackNesting=1
02-17 10:24:24.260: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=true mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
02-17 10:24:24.260: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
02-17 10:24:24.260: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
02-17 10:24:24.260: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{40cec708 in MainActivity{40cec5f0}}
02-17 10:24:24.260: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mActivity=com.PersianBeauty.MainActivity@40cec5f0
02-17 10:24:24.270: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mContainer=android.widget.FrameLayout{40ce3b28 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-480,621 #7f0a000d app:id/fram_home}
02-17 10:24:24.270: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mView=android.widget.LinearLayout{40eb4ef0 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0a000c app:id/lin_lay_home}
02-17 10:24:24.270: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #4: ModelProfileFragment{40e270a8 #4 id=0x7f0a001e}
02-17 10:24:24.270: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mFragmentId=#7f0a001e mContainerId=#7f0a001e mTag=null
02-17 10:24:24.270: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mState=5 mIndex=4 mWho=android:fragment:4 mBackStackNesting=0
02-17 10:24:24.270: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=true mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
02-17 10:24:24.270: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
02-17 10:24:24.270: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
02-17 10:24:24.270: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{40cec708 in MainActivity{40cec5f0}}
02-17 10:24:24.290: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mActivity=com.PersianBeauty.MainActivity@40cec5f0
02-17 10:24:24.290: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mContainer=android.widget.FrameLayout{40e25758 V.E..... ......I. 8,247-472,613 #7f0a001e app:id/frame_model_profile}
02-17 10:24:24.290: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mView=android.widget.ScrollView{40e1f458 VFED.V.. ......I. 0,0-464,366}
02-17 10:24:24.300: E/FragmentManager(7019):   Added Fragments:
02-17 10:24:24.300: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #0: HomeFragment{40cdedf0 #0 id=0x7f0a0001}
02-17 10:24:24.300: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #1: ModelProfileFragment{40e270a8 #4 id=0x7f0a001e}
02-17 10:24:24.300: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #2: VoteFragment{40edc820 #3 id=0x7f0a000d}
02-17 10:24:24.300: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #3: Frag_All_ModelList{40edee38 #2 id=0x7f0a0058}
02-17 10:24:24.300: E/FragmentManager(7019):   Back Stack:
02-17 10:24:24.300: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #0: BackStackEntry{40d068a8 #0}
02-17 10:24:24.300: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mName=null mIndex=0 mCommitted=true
02-17 10:24:24.300: E/FragmentManager(7019):       Operations:
02-17 10:24:24.310: E/FragmentManager(7019):         Op #0: REPLACE ModelsFragment{40ce06f0 #1 id=0x7f0a000d}
02-17 10:24:24.310: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #1: BackStackEntry{40edd0d0 #2}
02-17 10:24:24.310: E/FragmentManager(7019):       mName=null mIndex=2 mCommitted=true
02-17 10:24:24.310: E/FragmentManager(7019):       Operations:
02-17 10:24:24.310: E/FragmentManager(7019):         Op #0: REPLACE VoteFragment{40edc820 #3 id=0x7f0a000d}
02-17 10:24:24.310: E/FragmentManager(7019):           Removed: ModelsFragment{40ce06f0 #1 id=0x7f0a000d}
02-17 10:24:24.310: E/FragmentManager(7019):   Back Stack Indices:
02-17 10:24:24.310: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #0: BackStackEntry{40d068a8 #0}
02-17 10:24:24.320: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #1: null
02-17 10:24:24.320: E/FragmentManager(7019):     #2: BackStackEntry{40edd0d0 #2}
02-17 10:24:24.320: E/FragmentManager(7019):   mAvailBackStackIndices: [1]
02-17 10:24:24.320: E/FragmentManager(7019):   FragmentManager misc state:
02-17 10:24:24.320: E/FragmentManager(7019):     mActivity=com.PersianBeauty.MainActivity@40cec5f0
02-17 10:24:24.320: E/FragmentManager(7019):     mContainer=android.app.Activity$1@40cec780
02-17 10:24:24.320: E/FragmentManager(7019):     mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
02-17 10:24:24.320: E/FragmentManager(7019):   View Hierarchy:
02-17 10:24:24.330: E/FragmentManager(7019):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40ced7f0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-480,800}
02-17 10:24:24.330: E/FragmentManager(7019):       android.widget.LinearLayout{40cee878 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-480,800}
02-17 10:24:24.330: E/FragmentManager(7019):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{40cef4c8 V.ED.... ......I. 0,38-480,110 #1020359 android:id/action_bar_container}
02-17 10:24:24.330: E/FragmentManager(7019):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{40cf2970 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-480,72 #102035a android:id/action_bar}
02-17 10:24:24.330: E/FragmentManager(7019):             android.widget.LinearLayout{40cf9080 VFE...C. ......I. 0,0-182,72}
02-17 10:24:24.330: E/FragmentManager(7019):               com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{40cfa8e0 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-102,72}
02-17 10:24:24.330: E/FragmentManager(7019):                 android.widget.ImageView{40cfaea0 V.ED.... ......I. 0,21-39,51 #1020246 android:id/up}
02-17 10:24:24.340: E/FragmentManager(7019):                 android.widget.ImageView{40cfbe10 V.ED.... ......I. 34,12-96,60 #102002c android:id/home}
02-17 10:24:24.340: E/FragmentManager(7019):               android.widget.LinearLayout{40cfd800 V.E..... ......I. 102,0-182,72}
02-17 10:24:24.340: E/FragmentManager(7019):                 android.widget.ImageView{40cfdbe8 G.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020246 android:id/up}
02-17 10:24:24.340: E/FragmentManager(7019):                 android.widget.LinearLayout{40cfdf70 V.E..... ......I. 0,17-68,54}
02-17 10:24:24.350: E/FragmentManager(7019):                   android.widget.TextView{40cfe488 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-68,37 #102024d android:id/action_bar_title}
02-17 10:24:24.350: E/FragmentManager(7019):                   android.widget.TextView{40cff218 G.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #102024e android:id/action_bar_subtitle}
02-17 10:24:24.350: E/FragmentManager(7019):             com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView{40e39988 V.ED.... ......ID 480,0-480,72}
02-17 10:24:24.360: E/FragmentManager(7019):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{40cff930 G.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #102035b android:id/action_context_bar}
02-17 10:24:24.360: E/FragmentManager(7019):         android.widget.FrameLayout{40d02db8 V.ED.... ......ID 0,110-480,800 #1020002 android:id/content}
02-17 10:24:24.360: E/FragmentManager(7019):           android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{40d06a28 VFE..... .F....ID 0,0-480,690 #7f0a0000 app:id/drawer_layout}
02-17 10:24:24.370: E/FragmentManager(7019):             android.widget.FrameLayout{40d10140 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-480,690 #7f0a0001 app:id/frame_container}
02-17 10:24:24.370: E/FragmentManager(7019):               android.widget.LinearLayout{40d0c5a0 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-480,690 #7f0a000c app:id/lin_lay_home}
02-17 10:24:24.370: E/FragmentManager(7019):                 android.widget.FrameLayout{40ce3b28 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-480,621 #7f0a000d app:id/fram_home}
02-17 10:24:24.370: E/FragmentManager(7019):                   android.widget.LinearLayout{40eb4ef0 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0a000c app:id/lin_lay_home}
02-17 10:24:24.370: E/FragmentManager(7019):                     android.widget.FrameLayout{40eb52e0 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0a000d app:id/fram_home}
02-17 10:24:24.380: E/FragmentManager(7019):                       android.widget.ListView{410c40a8 V.ED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0a0022 app:id/list_home_model}
02-17 10:24:24.380: E/FragmentManager(7019):                 android.widget.LinearLayout{40cdd800 V.E..... ......I. 0,621-480,690 #7f0a000e app:id/linlay_home_button}
02-17 10:24:24.380: E/FragmentManager(7019):                   android.widget.Button{40d0ef50 VFED..C. ......I. 0,0-96,69 #7f0a000f app:id/btn_lin_models}
02-17 10:24:24.380: E/FragmentManager(7019):                   android.widget.Button{40ce98a8 VFED..C. ...P..I. 96,0-192,69 #7f0a0010 app:id/btn_lin_vote}
02-17 10:24:24.380: E/FragmentManager(7019):                   android.widget.Button{40d09350 VFED..C. ......I. 192,0-288,69 #7f0a0011 app:id/btn_lin_gallary}
02-17 10:24:24.380: E/FragmentManager(7019):                   android.widget.Button{40d09c58 VFED..C. ......I. 288,0-384,69 #7f0a0012 app:id/btn_lin_events}
02-17 10:24:24.390: E/FragmentManager(7019):                   android.widget.Button{40ce2118 VFED..C. ......I. 384,0-480,69 #7f0a0013 app:id/btn_lin_sponsers}
02-17 10:24:24.390: E/FragmentManager(7019):             android.widget.ListView{40d10a50 IFED.VC. ......ID -360,0-0,690 #7f0a0002 app:id/list_slidermenu}
02-17 10:24:24.390: E/FragmentManager(7019):               android.widget.RelativeLayout{40e22f10 V.E..... ......I. 15,15-345,50}
02-17 10:24:24.390: E/FragmentManager(7019):                 android.widget.ImageView{40e23598 V.ED.... ......ID 18,0-56,35 #7f0a0003 app:id/icon}
02-17 10:24:24.390: E/FragmentManager(7019):                 android.widget.TextView{40e28e90 V.ED.... ......ID 74,0-210,29 #7f0a0004 app:id/title}
02-17 10:24:24.390: E/FragmentManager(7019):                 android.widget.ImageView{40e294f8 V.ED.... ......ID 274,2-312,32 #7f0a0005 app:id/list_button}
02-17 10:24:24.390: E/FragmentManager(7019):               a
```

In that Model ,Vote ,Sponser ,Events  these are main button in that there  used nested fragment.
In that I have used addToBackStack() method .

Is another way to handle back Key Press in Fragment

Comment: what error and where ?

Comment: keshav sir ,I send error file, In these question i want go       [1]-->[1]a-->[1]a]i]-->1]a]i].                                        [2]-->[2]a-->[2]a]i]-->[2]a]i] it work properly but when i would like to go [1]-->[1]a-->[1]a]i]-->[1]a]i] --> 2 then it gives error

Comment: Where is ur main activity class ?

Comment: I have add Main Activity class

Comment: Where is this frame_models_list_detail  id ? Plz have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id