# App Development - Logcat errors and "Unfortunately <app> has stopped"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working on an independent app and am following some basic tutorials. From what I can tell, the code is virtually the same as the guides I'm following, but when I try to run the application on the emulator, I'm getting the "unfortunately  has stopped working" message. I'm having some difficulty interpreting the errors in the logcat because a lot of the directed lines of code are the default code created when I started the new files. Any help would be appreciiated, thanks

```
03-28 18:45:27.390: D/FragmentManager(1033):     mCreated=truemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
03-28 18:45:27.390: D/FragmentManager(1033):     mLoadersStarted=false
03-28 18:45:27.400: D/FragmentManager(1033):   Active Fragments in b3d357b8:
03-28 18:45:27.400: D/FragmentManager(1033):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{b3d35b68 #0 id=0x7f06003c}
03-28 18:45:27.400: D/FragmentManager(1033):       mFragmentId=#7f06003c mContainerId=#7f06003c mTag=null
03-28 18:45:27.400: D/FragmentManager(1033):       mState=0 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
03-28 18:45:27.400: D/FragmentManager(1033):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
03-28 18:45:27.400: D/FragmentManager(1033):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
03-28 18:45:27.400: D/FragmentManager(1033):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
03-28 18:45:27.400: D/FragmentManager(1033):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{b3d357b8 in MainActivity{b3d34660}}
03-28 18:45:27.400: D/FragmentManager(1033):       mActivity=com.example.cooldog.MainActivity@b3d34660
03-28 18:45:27.400: D/FragmentManager(1033):   Added Fragments:
03-28 18:45:27.400: D/FragmentManager(1033):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{b3d35b68 #0 id=0x7f06003c}
03-28 18:45:27.410: D/FragmentManager(1033):   FragmentManager misc state:
03-28 18:45:27.410: D/FragmentManager(1033):     mActivity=com.example.cooldog.MainActivity@b3d34660
03-28 18:45:27.170: D/dalvikvm(1033): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 6% free 2860K/3012K, paused 52ms, total 54ms
03-28 18:45:27.180: I/dalvikvm-heap(1033): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.575MB for 756876-byte allocation
03-28 18:45:27.260: D/dalvikvm(1033): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3596K/3752K, paused 74ms, total 74ms
03-28 18:45:27.380: E/FragmentManager(1033): No view found for id 0x7f06003c (com.example.cooldog:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b3d35b68 #0 id=0x7f06003c}
03-28 18:45:27.380: E/FragmentManager(1033): Activity state:
03-28 18:45:27.390: D/FragmentManager(1033):   Local FragmentActivity b3d34660 State:
03-28 18:45:27.420: D/FragmentManager(1033):     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@b3d36130
03-28 18:45:27.420: D/FragmentManager(1033):     mCurState=2 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
03-28 18:45:27.420: D/FragmentManager(1033):   View Hierarchy:
03-28 18:45:27.420: D/FragmentManager(1033):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b3d3acc0 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-28 18:45:27.430: D/FragmentManager(1033):       com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{b3d3bdb8 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020313 android:id/action_bar_overlay_layout}
03-28 18:45:27.430: D/FragmentManager(1033):         android.widget.FrameLayout{b3d3d528 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
03-28 18:45:27.430: D/FragmentManager(1033):           android.widget.RelativeLayout{b3d52388 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f06003d app:id/RelativeLayout1}
03-28 18:45:27.430: D/FragmentManager(1033):             android.widget.TextView{b3d33db8 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f06003e app:id/TextView1}
03-28 18:45:27.440: D/FragmentManager(1033):             android.widget.Button{b3d336a0 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f06003f app:id/readWish}
03-28 18:45:27.440: D/FragmentManager(1033):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{b3d3dac0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020314 android:id/action_bar_container}
03-28 18:45:27.440: D/FragmentManager(1033):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{b3d40678 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020315 android:id/action_bar}
03-28 18:45:27.440: D/FragmentManager(1033):             android.widget.LinearLayout{b3d40e58 V.....C. ... 0,0-0,0}
03-28 18:45:27.440: D/FragmentManager(1033):               com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{b3d44d30 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-28 18:45:27.440: D/FragmentManager(1033):                 android.widget.ImageView{b3d45278 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102025a android:id/up}
03-28 18:45:27.440: D/FragmentManager(1033):                 android.widget.ImageView{b3d463d8 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102002c android:id/home}
03-28 18:45:27.440: D/FragmentManager(1033):               android.widget.LinearLayout{b3d47a88 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-28 18:45:27.440: D/FragmentManager(1033):                 android.widget.TextView{b3d47fa8 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020265 android:id/action_bar_title}
03-28 18:45:27.440: D/FragmentManager(1033):                 android.widget.TextView{b3d48d10 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020266 android:id/action_bar_subtitle}
03-28 18:45:27.440: D/FragmentManager(1033):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{b3d49478 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020316 android:id/action_context_bar}
03-28 18:45:27.440: D/FragmentManager(1033):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{b3d4bee8 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020317 android:id/split_action_bar}
03-28 18:45:27.460: D/AndroidRuntime(1033): Shutting down VM
03-28 18:45:27.460: W/dalvikvm(1033): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a72ba8)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): Process: com.example.cooldog, PID: 1033
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cooldog/com.example.cooldog.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f06003c (com.example.cooldog:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b3d35b68 #0 id=0x7f06003c}
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f06003c (com.example.cooldog:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b3d35b68 #0 id=0x7f06003c}
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
03-28 18:45:27.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     ... 11 more
03-28 18:45:33.480: I/Process(1033): Sending signal. PID: 1033 SIG: 9
```

==============================================================

## CODE

==============================================================

## MainActivity (java file)

```
package com.example.cooldog;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//Fields//
int wishes;
Button read;
TextView currentlyReadWish; //travis's display


//Methods//

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    wishes = 0;
    read = (Button) findViewById(R.id.readWish);
    currentlyReadWish = (TextView) findViewById(wishes); //REPLACE WITH DATABASE MSG
    read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //new View.onClickListener might be wrong, this changes whats already on the screen, we want it to transition to another one with a different view entirely
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Auto-generated method stub WHAT HAPPENS WHEN U CLICK
            //BRINGS YOU TO NEW SCREEN OR POPS UP A ENCOMPASSING WINDOW ON ABOVE SCREEN
            //DISPLAYS WISH
            currentlyReadWish.setText("THEWISHMSG");
        }   
    });
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

==============================================================

## main_fragment (xml file)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ice_cream"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.cooldog.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="207dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/greeting1"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/readWish"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

==============================================================

## AndroidManifest (xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.cooldog"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.cooldog.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> <!-- WHAT ACTIVITY OPENS UPON LAUNCH, HAVE JUST ONE IDIOT -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name="com.example.cooldog.WishingCenter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.cooldog.WISHINGCENTER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

==============================================================

## Transition1 (java file)

```
package com.example.cooldog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Transition1 extends Activity {

MediaPlayer transitionSong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ice_cream);
    transitionSong = MediaPlayer.create(Transition1.this, R.raw.beasts);
    transitionSong.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent openNextWindow = new Intent("com.example.cooldog.WISHINGCENTER");
                startActivity(openNextWindow);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    transitionSong.release();
    finish();
}
```

}

==============================================================

## WishingCenter (java file)

```
package com.example.cooldog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class WishingCenter extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ice_cream);
}
```

}

==============================================================

## ice_cream (xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ice_cream">
</FrameLayout>
```

==============================================================

## strings (xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<string android:id="@+id/app_name" name="app_name">cooldog</string>
<string android:id="@+id/hello_world" name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string android:id="@+id/action_settings" name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string android:id="@+id/greeting1" name="greeting1">Welcome back, </string>
<string android:id="@+id/greeting2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"       android:layout_width="wrap_content" name="greeting2"> new messages</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Please post your code. Based on the logcat my guess is you are doing a `setText()` with an `int` rather than a `String`.

Comment: Sorry about that, have added all the implemented code so far

Answer (score 0):

I think you have specified the wrong layout in `setContentView()` of the `onCreate()` method of the Fragment activity.

[Android Fragment no view found for ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out some of the default code that was automatically implemented when I started the app is what was causing my issues. After deleting it, it worked as intended. thanks all for your help and contributions.

Comment: You might want to voluntarily delete this question unless you think it will be useful to other people in future.