# Eclypse:the method add(int fragment) in the type fragmenttransaction is not applicable

Tags: android, eclipse

Im starting Android developing and learning java. My problem is the "the method add(int fragment) in the type fragmenttransaction is not applicable" error in

```
     package com.example.myfirstapp;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
   <==here==>             .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
            public PlaceholderFragment() { }
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_message,
                          container, false);
                  return rootView;
            }
        }
    }
```

when i used import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; elypse show no error but on my phone app crash
Thanks For Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use getSupportFragmentManager() if you use android.support.v4.app.Fragment only. Try using getFragmentManager() or could you copy the error log?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TGDCbT9g This is the error message. I tryed use getFragmentManager()  but app also crashing

Comment: This is not the problem with fragment manager. It is the problem with your layout xml files. Are you using the same layout for the activity and the fragment? Could you show the layout file also? Also have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id

Comment: My xml file http://pastebin.com/bQfyu4gn i dont have any fragment_activity.xml
 greetings