# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090057 for fragment" - Android Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, r.java-file

Currently working on an app, which has a MainActivity with a Fragment that contains multiple buttons. I cannot start another activity when clicking on the buttons.

I keep getting an error here saying

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090057
>   for fragment
>   [image: Logcat view for Error]

I have two classes; a NavigationDrawer class (my MainActivity)

And a class named StartingFragment (which I want to be the main view when the drawer is closed/not active).

Here is the code that the error seems to refer to (from NavDrawer.java):

```
        /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
        /** Starts an Activity when item is clicked */
        private void selectItem(int position) {
                // Create a new fragment and specify the tea type
                // to show based on position
                Fragment fragment = new StartingFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(StartingFragment.TEA_TYPE_POS, position);
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
                FragmentManager fragManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_replace, fragment)
                                .commit();

                // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                setTitle(navDrawerTitles[position]);
                navDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }
```

I looked at this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8158916 and I see that **R.id.fragment_replace** should be *a child* of the **R.layout.nav_drawer**, which is the case here.
I also posted a very similar question a few days ago, although previously the app would just crash from the start; now it crashes on Button/AlertDialog clicks

However, I don't know what to adjust in my code. 
***I get this error whenever I try to click on a button (and then click on the neutral/positive button of the AlertDialog that follows) from StartingFragment.java & starting_fragment.xml***

Logcat Text:

> 01-02 17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 01-02 17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814): Process:
>   com.fv4.tea.teatime.first, PID: 26814 01-02 17:16:13.642:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26814): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.fv4.tea.teatime.first/com.fv4.teatime.tea.app.OolongTeaActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090057
>   (com.fv4.tea.teatime.first:id/fragment_replace) for fragment
>   StartingFragment{41c95b40 #0 id=0x7f090057} 01-02 17:16:13.642:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26814):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
>   01-02 17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
>   01-02 17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 01-02
>   17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
>   01-02 17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 01-02
>   17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 01-02 17:16:13.642:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26814):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146) 01-02
>   17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-02
>   17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 01-02 17:16:13.642:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26814):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
>   01-02 17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 01-02
>   17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-02 17:16:13.642:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26814): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090057
>   (com.fv4.tea.teatime.first:id/fragment_replace) for fragment
>   StartingFragment{41c95b40 #0 id=0x7f090057} 01-02 17:16:13.642:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26814):  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:882)
>   01-02 17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
>   01-02 17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):  at
>   android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684) 01-02
>   17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
>   01-02 17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240) 01-02
>   17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
>   01-02 17:16:13.642: E/AndroidRuntime(26814):  ... 11 more

Comment: This is so strange. I even checked OolongTeaActivity, and there seems to be nothing wrong. I haven't modified the activity since making changes to the NavDrawer or StartingFragment

Comment: Remove the links to pastebin since you have deleted the posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed the issue! I was writing `extends NavigationDrawer` on all of my classes, and so when I changed it to `extends Activity`, that fixed the problem, and now everything is working smoothly. All set now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace a fragment that is statically placed in an xml layout file. You should create a container (e.g. a ViewGroup) in the layout and then add the fragment programatically using FragmentTransaction.

Comment: I'm not replacing the fragment though. I'm simply switching to a different activity....Unless that's the same exact thing?

Comment: fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_replace, fragment).commit(); In this line u replacing fragment that is statically placed in xml.

Comment: OK. I see. I'll add the Fragment programmatically and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: Hi. I added the fragment programmatically, but I am getting the same exact error as before