# Android viewpager inside dialogfragment, app crashed with no view found for id using API 17

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library, android-dialogfragment, android-nested-fragment

for the issue in question. Tried Searching for solutions and says getChildFragmentManager/getSupportFragmentManager should be used, but the problem is even with updated android sdk lib using the android support v13 (which has v4) installed, Eclipse Luna still cannot recognize getChildFragmentManager/getSupportFragmentManager. I also tried importing the support.app.v4 namespace but that will only make the ScreenSlidePagerAdapter's FragmentManager throw a type error.

DialogFragment Class which contains the view pager:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class EnlargeItemPicture extends DialogFragment {

/**
 * The number of pages to show in the view slider
 */
private static int NUM_PAGES = 1; // [Temp] set the total page number according to total items under current selected category instead next time

/**
 * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
 * and next wizard steps.
 */
private ViewPager pager;

/**
 * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
 */
private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

private View customDialogView; 
private String imagePath;
private String itemName;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // instead of inflating the activity with imageview only, inflate the viewpager activity here

    customDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager, null);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    pager = (ViewPager) customDialogView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(super.getFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

   /**
    * Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    * Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    * customDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_item_picture, null);
    * ImageView img = (ImageView) customDialogView.findViewById(R.id.enlargepicture);
    * img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
    */

    builder.setView(customDialogView)
        .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();       
            }
        });

    return builder.create();
}

public EnlargeItemPicture(String picturePath, String itemName)
{
    imagePath = picturePath;
    this.itemName = itemName;
}

 /**
 * A simple pager adapter that represents n objects, in
 * sequence.
 */
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ScreenSlidePageItemViewFragment.create(position, "");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

ScreenSlidePageItemViewFragment Class that holds the fragment to be inserted to viewpager:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ScreenSlidePageItemViewFragment extends Fragment {

/**
 * The argument key for the page number this fragment represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";
/**
 * The argument key for the item Title this fragment represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_ITEM_TITLE = "item_title";

/**
 * The fragment's page number, which is set to the argument value for {@link #ARG_PAGE}.
 */
private int pageNumber;

private String itemTitle;

/**
 * Factory method for this fragment class. Constructs a new fragment for the given page number and Title.
 */
public static ScreenSlidePageItemViewFragment create(int pageNumber, String itemTitle) {
    ScreenSlidePageItemViewFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageItemViewFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
    args.putString(ARG_ITEM_TITLE, itemTitle);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

/**
 * Factory method for this fragment class. Constructs a new fragment.
 */
public ScreenSlidePageItemViewFragment()
{  }

/**
 * Gets the arguments and pass to this properties
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    itemTitle = getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_TITLE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.item_page_view, container, true);

   /// TODO: add listeners to each views here

    return rootView;
}

/**
 * Returns the page number represented by this fragment object.
 */
public int getPageNumber() {
    return pageNumber;
}

/**
 * Returns the item title represented by this fragment object.
 */
public String getItemTitle(){
    return itemTitle;
}
}
```

Here is the XML file for layout with viewpager:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is the XML file for layout that will be inserted to viewpager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/itemimage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/minusbtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="-" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addbtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/minusbtn"
                android:text="+" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemTotal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/addbtn"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addbtn"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addbtn"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I'm at lost here, or perhaps i had it implemented wrong? or something that i had missed?

Plenty of Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi was able to access getSupportFragmentManager function by carefully replacing each to use the support lib, but still get the no view found for id ??. I am still looking for a way on how to access getChildFragmentManager function and see if it helps.

Comment: Read the answer, which solves the undefined function problem. after using the getChildFragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager function, a new error arises which is Fragment does not have a view. I am currently researching about what causes the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be an answer in a way, at least it solve one of the causes which gives a new type of exception in which i will post another question if i cannot resolved it with answers from similar problems. The one that got resolved here is I am now able to use the getChildFragmentManager and getSupportFragmentManager function and the answer can be found here: [Eclipse Android missing getSupportedFragmentManager and getChildFragmentManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355701/eclipse-android-missing-getsupportedfragmentmanager-and-getchildfragmentmanager).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState);
```

Instead of:

```
Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState);
```

It's helped for me.

Also, check out this link:

[fragments in viewpager, no view found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858356/fragments-in-viewpager-no-view-found-error/39726590#39726590)