# Eclipse Android missing getSupportFragmentManager and getChildFragmentManager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment, android-nested-fragment

Hi I tried using the android supported lib v4 as well as v13 instead of android app lib but eclipse still cannot recognize the getSupportedFragmentManager and getChildFragmentManager functions. Are there any steps I need to take in order fro eclipse to recognize both functions? 
Currently using Eclipse luna with latest android sdk, targeting api 17 platform.

I need either function to see why the app crashes with no view found for id ?? when using viewpager inside dialogfragment.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you please post your code here ?

Comment: The codes can be found here, on my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335482/android-viewpager-inside-dialogfragment-app-crashed-with-no-view-found-for-id-u

Comment: @Kiloreux I found the reason why eclipse cant recognize both functions and that is because while getSupportFragmentManager is available in supported lib v13 but both function are only available in support lib v4 which is weird considering v13 is higher and v4 is included. perhaps they removed getChildFragmentManager function in v13 for some reason. Discovered when using the software provided here http://jd.benow.ca/ to search for the function on which class they reside and viola, v13 actually don't have getChildFragmentManager in any of the classes available and it's only existed in v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why eclipse cant recognize both functions and that is because while getSupportFragmentManager is available in supported lib v13 but both function are only available in support lib v4 which is weird considering v13 is higher and v4 is included. perhaps they removed getChildFragmentManager function in v13 for some reason. Discovered when using the software provided here jd.benow.ca to search for the function on which class they reside and viola, v13 actually don't have getChildFragmentManager in any of the classes available and it's only existed in v4, so for now, if getChildFragmentManager is needed just use support lib v4 for now or find a way to use both support lib v4 and 13. happy programming using support lib v4 and v13 guys.