# Android - No view found for fragment, changing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello currently I am working on a Android project on Android Studio where I can switch Fragments using FragmentPagerAdapter, using root fragments for each, so when I was using one fragment it worked perfectly but when i wanted to implement the second one it gave me the following error;

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c00ae (net.beardboy.aarcapp:id/root_frame_graphs) for fragment GraphsFragment{d178606 #0 id=0x7f0c00ae}
```

I swap between fragments using getSupportFragmentManager(), as I said it worked fine the first time I used but then it gave me error. this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ReportsAdapter.ReportCallBacks {

    ProgressDialog progressDialogReports;
    ProgressDialog progressDialogGraphs;
    ProgressDialog progressDialogSettings;

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    FragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    User currentUser;
    SessionStateManager sessionStateManager;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    ReportsFragments reportsFragments;
    GraphsFragment graphsFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sessionStateManager = new SessionStateManager(this);
        currentUser = new User();
        currentUser = sessionStateManager.getCurrentUser();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        graphsFragment = new GraphsFragment();


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabBarLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        fragmentPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
            private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = 3;

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:

                        try {
                            getReportsdata();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return new RootFragmentReports();
                    case 1:
                            getGraphsdata();

                        return new RootFragmentGraphs();
                    case 2:
                        return new RootFragmentSettings();
                }


                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return FRAGMENT_COUNT;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return "Reportes";
                    case 1:
                        return "Graficas";
                    case 2:
                        return "Pagos";
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }
        };

        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }

        });


    }


    public void getReportsdata() throws JSONException {

        progressDialogReports = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.please_wait), getString(R.string.downloading_data), true, false);


        JSONObject jsonUser = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jsonMain = new JSONObject();
        jsonUser.put(JSONKeys.KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN, currentUser.getAccess_token());
        jsonUser.put(JSONKeys.KEY_CLIENTE_ID, currentUser.getCilenteId());
        jsonUser.put(JSONKeys.KEY_NAME, currentUser.getName());
        jsonUser.put(JSONKeys.KEY_EMAIL, currentUser.getEmail());
        jsonMain.put(JSONKeys.KEY_AARC_USER, jsonUser);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, JSONKeys.URL_REPORTES_POR_CLIENTE, jsonMain, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                progressDialogReports.dismiss();

                try {
                    ArrayList<JSONReport> jsonReports = (ArrayList<JSONReport>) JSONParser.parseJSONReport(response);
                    replaceFragment(jsonReports);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialogReports.dismiss();
                        Log.i("errr", error.toString());
                        DialogUtil.createSimpleDialog(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.error_downloading_data), error.toString()).show();

                    }
                });
        int socketTimeout = 180000;//3 minutes - change to what you want
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);


    }

    public void getGraphsdata() {

        ArrayList<Graph> graphArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Graph graficas = new Graph();
            graficas.setAnalisis(i);
            graficas.setSucursal("descripcion" + i);
            graphArrayList.add(graficas);
        }




        ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

        entries.add(new Entry(2f, 0));
        entries.add(new Entry(4f, 1));
        entries.add(new Entry(3f, 2));
        entries.add(new Entry(4f, 3));


        LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(entries, "Fecha");

        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        labels.add("January");
        labels.add("February");
        labels.add("January");
        labels.add("February");

        replaceFragmentGraph(graphArrayList);

    }

    private void replaceFragment(ArrayList<JSONReport> jsonReports) {
        reportsFragments = new ReportsFragments();
        ReportsAdapter reportsAdapter;
        reportsAdapter = new ReportsAdapter(MainActivity.this, jsonReports);
        reportsAdapter.setReportAdapterCallBacks(MainActivity.this);
        reportsFragments.setComplaintsAdapter(reportsAdapter);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.root_frame_actividades, reportsFragments)
                .commit();

    }


    private void replaceFragmentGraph(ArrayList<Graph> datos) {

        graphsFragment = new GraphsFragment();
        //Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        //bundle.putParcelable("datos", (Parcelable) datos);
        //graphsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.root_frame_graphsa, graphsFragment)
                //.addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();


    }


    @Override
    public void OnReportCallBacks(JSONReport jsonReport) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReportsDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(JSONKeys.KEY_FOLIOB, jsonReport.getFoliob());
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_acitivity_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

The error started to appear when I added the GraphsFragment in the getSupportFragmentManager(), I double checked the layouts's ID are the correct ones and so, but since in the error the **ID 0x7f0c00ae** and later on the same line the same id appears again, forgive me for my bad english. Thank you all.

**EDIT**
My GraphsFragment class

```
public class GraphsFragment extends Fragment {
LineChart chart;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graphs, container, false);

    chart = (LineChart) rootview.findViewById(R.id.linechart);

    return rootview;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


   //code


}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}


}
```

fragments_graphs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/linechart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout
```

RootFragmentGraphs class

```
public class RootFragmentGraphs extends Fragment{
    private static final String TAG = "RootFragmentGraphs";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_root_fragment_graficas, container, false);



        return view;
    }


}
```

fragment_root_fragment_graficas.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_frame_graphs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.RootFragmentGraphs">

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please can you add the code for the GraphsFragment

Comment: Can you please include the code for your Activity's onCreate and then also include the XML where you declared your Fragments?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the updates, please include the code for your Activity's onCreate as well.

Comment: Here you go, thank you @ishmaelMakitla

Comment: Great! Now, for your case, please show us the XML for layout `activity_main`

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be because you have inflated the wrong layout (XML) - meaning the `R.id.root_frame_graphs` may not exist in that layout file. 
One expects to find something like this in your layout file (using `FrameLayout`):

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/root_frame_graphs"              
  android:...
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The ID (`R.id.root_frame_graphs`) passed into FragmentTransaction.replace() must be a child of the layout specified in setContentView() - which I suggested that you include in your question. My suspicion is that you may be facing the same issue as the one solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id?rq=1)

Comment: While you might be right with concept of wrong layout file being inflated, the sentence `Specifically you must have both Fragments in the XML file` in context of use `replace()` on them disqualifies the whole answer

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, I understand your point - but perhaps I was misled by the fact that he is referring to two different IDs - `root_frame_actividades` and `root_frame_graphs` - this made me think that he has "place-holders" for both...I hope this makes sense.

Comment: But your answer still features sentence I quoted which simply is wrong, due to the fact you are unable to remove fragment not added from code.