# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00bf () for fragment

Tags: java, android

Error code show:

> 09-15 11:20:26.413 16914-16914/com.ats_school.bsdp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main v
>                                                                        Process: com.ats_school.bsdp, PID: 16914
>                                                                        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00bf
>   (com.ats_school.bsdp:id/mission_menu) for fragment
>   MissionParty{6ecf0ff #0 id=0x7f0d00bf}
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

ActivityMain.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
//  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

   // private static ImageView daily_sounds, daily_news, daily_videos, songParty, gallery, notice, mission, policy, history;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //onClickImageButtonListener();
        //onClickImageViewListener();


        final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        //DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
            //Create an alertdialog
            AlertDialog.Builder Checkbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            Checkbuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.about_us);
            Checkbuilder.setTitle("Error!");
            Checkbuilder.setMessage("Check Your Internet Connection");
            //Builder Retry

        } else {

//        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
//        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    Log.d("Navigation", "selected" + item.getTitle());
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle());

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.mission_menu:
                            goToMissionMenu();
                            break;
                        case R.id.policy_menu:
                            goToPolicyMenu();
                            break;

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void goToMissionMenu() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        MissionParty missionParty = new MissionParty();
        transaction.replace(R.id.mission_menu, missionParty);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void goToPolicyMenu() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        PolicyMenu policyMenu = new PolicyMenu();
        transaction.replace(R.id.policy_menu, policyMenu);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.ats_school.bsdp.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_container">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:shrinkColumns="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.ats_school.bsdp.MainActivity">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layoutDirection="inherit"
        android:padding="10dp"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/daily_sounds"
                android:src="@drawable/daily_news"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/daily_sounds"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/daily_sounds"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/pressed_green"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/daily_news"
                android:src="@drawable/news"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/daily_news"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/daily_news"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/pressed_green"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/daily_videos"
                android:src="@drawable/videos"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/daily_videos"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/daily_videos"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/pressed_green"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
   </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/pressed_green"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MissionParty.java (Fragment file)

```
public class MissionParty extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match

    public MissionParty() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mission_party, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Fragment no view found for ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id)

Comment: @Sieng Champa: where is your "R.id.mission_menu"  in layout??

Comment: where is fragment_mission_party layout