# App crashes while trying to navigate to fragment from Image View

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, onclicklistener, cardview

App crashes when I click on ImageView.

Trying to navigate to a fragment with card view after clicking on Image View. There is fragment ghosting problem as well but that code is commented for now.
I tried fixing that as well but was not successful.

This is my code:

**mainroute.java:**

```java
 wiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            //@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();//.findFragmentByTag("WifiFragment");

                /*if (mFragment == null) {
                    // wifiFragment = WifiFragment.newInstance();
                    mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.WifiLayout, wifiFragment, "WifiFragment");
                } else {
                    wifiFragment = (WifiFragment) mFragment;*/

                    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    WifiFragment wifiFragment = new WifiFragment();
                    mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.WifiLayout, wifiFragment);
                    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
                    fICardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                }

            });
```

**the logcat is:**

```java
2019-02-15 21:32:08.960 15780-15780/com.felixxiong.android.city E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.felixxiong.android.city, PID: 15780
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07002f (com.penghaoxiong.android.cityexploration:id/WifiLayout) for fragment WifiFragment{6e89def #4 id=0x7f07002f}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1454)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit

...
2019-02-15 21:32:09.774 3275-15841/? E/EntrySyncManager: Cannot determine account name: drop request
2019-02-15 21:32:09.775 3275-15841/? E/NowController: Failed to access data from EntryProvider. ExecutionException.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.eA(SourceFile:85)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(SourceFile:23)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.l.get(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbB(SourceFile:49)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbA(SourceFile:181)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.bh.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.at.run(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.ar.az(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.q.ap(SourceFile:7)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.p.run(SourceFile:32)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bt.execute(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.b(SourceFile:275)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.addListener(SourceFile:135)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.p.b(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.h.a(SourceFile:16)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.h.a(SourceFile:13)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbB(SourceFile:47)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbA(SourceFile:181) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.bh.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.at.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6) 
2019-02-15 21:32:09.777 1814-1827/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

I was tried this post:[Android Fragment no view found for ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id/16843590)

I tried to find my r.java flie,i was find my wifilayout id:
r.java:

```java
public static final int WifiLayout=0x7f07002f;
```

The same issue is occuring in another function in this fragment.

I tried to `getChildFragmentManager()`:

```java
noButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                NoteFragment noteFragment = new NoteFragment();
                mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.NoteLayout, noteFragment);
                mFragmentTransaction.commit();
                fICardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        });
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So what are these `R.id....Layout`s you're trying to use as container layout for the fragment? Note the container layout needs to be already there (e.g. in the hosting activity), it cannot be part of the fragment being added.

Comment: I tried to make a CardView, and dynamic switching ImageView to make CardView show, this cardView was in mainActivity XML, and to load fragment, and have ghosting bug(mainRoute.java-comment code). In old vision, this was successful to on click...

Answer (score 0):

If your layout file WifiLayout is in the layout folder, you have to use `R.layout.WifiLayout` instead of `R.id.WifiLayout`.

And that's the same with all of your layout files.

Best

Comment: My `WifiLayout` was the `android:id` in xml file，isn't the layout flie name.
when i was change `id` to `layout`, android studio was tip me ‘Expected resource of type id’...

Comment: Can you post your layout xml file plz ?

Comment: Just the fragment have a cardview, and visibility is gone, and other XML:wifi frag XML and note frag XML layout have a ID…