# No view found error while that I try to sending data from an activity to a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
public class Language_Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
private Languages_Courses_Fragment lcf;
private List<slide> firstSlides;
private ViewPager courceSlidePager,viewPager_language;
private TabLayout tablayout_language;
private Button button;
private TextView lname;
private ImageView limage;
private Button intbutton, discbutton, cbutton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_language_profile);
    button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    lname= findViewById(R.id.nameoflanguage);
    limage= findViewById(R.id.imageoflanguage);
    tablayout_language=findViewById(R.id.tablayout_language);
    viewPager_language=findViewById(R.id.viewPager_language);
    courceSlidePager=findViewById(R.id.courceSlidePager);


    FragmentAdapter adapter=new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.AddFragment(new Languages_Courses_Fragment(),"Introduction");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Languages_Books_Fragment(),"Courses/Books");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Languages_Discuss_Fragment(),"Discuss");

    viewPager_language.setAdapter(adapter);
    tablayout_language.setupWithViewPager(viewPager_language);

    String langimage = getIntent().getStringExtra("coursephoto");
    String langname = getIntent().getStringExtra("coursename");
    String ldescription = getIntent().getStringExtra("coursedescription");
    lname.setText(langname);
    Picasso.get().load(langimage).into(limage);

    Languages_Courses_Fragment cfragment= new Languages_Courses_Fragment ();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("description", ldescription);
    cfragment.setArguments(bundle);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, cfragment, cfragment.getTag())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();





E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.slidersample, PID: 22952
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a007f 
(com.example.slidersample:id/fragment_container) for fragment Languages_Courses_Fragment{d35baaf #0 
id=0x7f0a007f}
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1454)
    at 
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1425)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7825)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Hi, I'm trying to sending a data from an activity to a fragment, but Android Studio gives an error which is calledd "no view found for fragment". How can I solve it?
Hi, I'm trying to sending a data from an activity to a fragment, but Android Studio gives an error which is calledd "no view found for fragment". How can I solve it?

```
public class Languages_Courses_Fragment extends Fragment {

PieChart salary_language;
TextView ldesript;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_languages_courses, container, false);
    salary_language =view.findViewById(R.id.salary_language);

    /*ldesript = view.findViewById(R.id.ldesc);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String myValue = bundle.getString("desc");
    ldesript.setText(myValue);*/

    String str = getArguments().getString("description");
    ldesript.setText(str);
    pieChartValues();

    return  view;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Fragment no view found for ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. Still same.

Comment: Please share the layout xml for the Activity. And does your Activity implementation override `onStart()` ?