# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity, No view found for id 0x7f0a0076 (.......) for fragment MainFragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments

This question is not the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id). Actually my project is working fine but when I am generating .aar file and integrating with another project then it gives me the above exception. Independently it works fine. By the way  this problem raised since my android-studio got updated to 3.6. bdfore the update, things were working pretty well.

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_main_activity, new MainFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

And here goes my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container_main_activity"/>
```

Full Exception is

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.....MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0076 (......:id/content) for fragment MainFragment{bf2d515} (af12e94e-1469-47f3-82fd-56ec6a2acd98) id=0x7f0a0076}
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0076 (com.plavaga.vyuha.v2:id/content) for fragment MainFragment{bf2d515} (af12e94e-1469-47f3-82fd-56ec6a2acd98) id=0x7f0a0076}
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:305)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2621)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2569)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
>           at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6683)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2687)

Comment: When you try to launch the activity you are passing an id which is not valid `IllegalArgumentException` . So when you try to call the main function using that id you are not able to do it. Problem is at `replace(R.id.container_main_activity`

Comment: Thanks @GuillermoVidal for quick reply but i am sorry i didn't get you. can you explain furthur?