# getSupportFragmentManager findFragmentByTag always returning null when trying to find a child fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have read 10 stackoverflow threads out why my case of getSupportFragmentManager findFragmentByTag is returning null. I've been trying to debug everything for over 2 hours and still can't figure out why.

I have a Child Fragment that is adding another Child Fragment:

```
 getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.fragmentsubreddit_container, fragmentViewpager, "FRAGMENT_VIEWPAGER")
      .commit();
 getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
 activity.findTheFragment();
```

In my activity's method:

```
public void findTheFragment(){
        FragmentViewpager fragmentViewpager = (FragmentViewpager) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_VIEWPAGER");
        if(fragmentViewpager == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "findTheFragment: Returning null");
        }
    }
```

What am I doing incorrectly that `findFragmentByTag` is returning null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FragmentManager` returned by `Activity.getSupportFragmentManager()` is different from the one returned by `Fragment.getChildFragmentManager()`.

If you want to perform a fragment transaction from the `Fragment` level, but be able to "see" it at the `Activity` level, then you should use `Fragment.getParentFragmentManager()` (or `Fragment.getFragmentManager()` on older versions of the AndroidX library).

Comment: I've replaced the ```getChildFragmentManager()``` with ```getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()``` but it return's ```No view found for id for fragment FragmentViewpager```. I've also tried ```activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()``` but it also it returns that same error. https://i.imgur.com/amKyPzc.png Is this what you meant?

Comment: I'm trying to add a Child Fragment to a Fragment(That is also a child Fragment). If I use getFragmentManager() it's giving me that error https://stackoverflow.com/a/28360506/11110509

Comment: Then you will not be able to access that fragment directly from the activity. You will have to go through the parent fragment. `Fragment parent = getSupportFragmentManager().find(PARENT_TAG); Fragment child = parent.getChildFragmentManager().find(CHILD_TAG);`

Comment: I thought that would work, but it unfortunately doesn't https://i.imgur.com/eNV9TkO.png The parent fragment gets found, but the child is still returning null https://i.imgur.com/Sfj988j.png

Comment: I take that back! I was using the parent's parent fragment(FragmentSearch is two parent's above) once I made it one level lower, your answer worked perfectly. Damn that took a long time to debug. Thanks a bunch. https://i.imgur.com/3BIX1d3.png