# No view found for ID

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to achieve Fragment to Fragment transaction with `onOptionsItemSelected` but I keep getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id

I also read this thread:
[Android Fragment no view found for ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id) and applied some answer to my code but it is not solve my problem

Here is my HomeFragment.java

```
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //Set Toolbar for Fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu,menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cart_fragment_layout,new CartFragment())
                .commitNow();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My fragment_cart.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cart_fragment_layout"
    tools:context="com.example.fragment.CartFragment"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/cart_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cart_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:text="Cart Fragment" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and my CartFragment.java

```
public class CartFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

My MainActivity.java just in case, I set HomeFragment as default:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frament_container,
                new HomeFragment()).commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;

            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_menu:
                    selectedFragment = new MenuFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_user:
                    selectedFragment = new UserFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_more:
                    selectedFragment = new MoreFragment();
                    break;
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frament_container,
                    selectedFragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Is your toolbar R.id.main_toolbar in fragment layout or in activity layout??

Comment: Also add the crash log

Comment: It is in fragment layout

Comment: [link] (https://imgur.com/a/uYAeAjZ) this is the crashlog

Comment: `cart_fragment_layout` do you have this layout?

Comment: @lyncx `cart_fragment_layout` is the id of the FrameLayout inside CartFragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id you use in a fragment transaction is NOT the view id of a view in the fragment.  Its the id of the fragment stub view in the layout you're popping the fragment into.  So you're passing in the wrong id.  I can't tell you what the right one is, as you don't give us the xml of your main layout.

Basically the fragment transaction looks for the id you pass out in the context root layout, then pops out what's already there and replaces it with your fragment.

Comment: Thank for your reply,  I just gave an id for CartFragment in nav_graph.xml, and replace the correct id inside .replace() but still no view found

Comment: It wouldn't be in nav_graph.  It would be in activity_main.xml.  That's your root content view.

Comment: Also, your onCreate of your main activity will also cause problems-  you try to call findViewById before calling setContentView, which will then always return null because there can't be a matching id if there is no content view.