# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0800c4

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, illegalargumentexception, fragmentmanager

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textview=findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int num=0;
            while(true) {
                num = random.nextInt(7);
                if(num!=0)
                    break;
            }

            Log.i("","Button Clicked");
            int finalNum = num;
            textview.setText(Integer.toString(finalNum));
            if(num==1)
               fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frag_one, One.class, null)
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .addToBackStack("name") // name can be null
                    .commit();
            else if(num==2)
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frag_two, Two.class, null)
                        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                        .addToBackStack("name") // name can be null
                        .commit();
            else if(num==3)
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frag_three, Three.class, null)
                        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                        .addToBackStack("name") // name can be null
                        .commit();
            else if(num==4)
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frag_four, Four.class, null)
                        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                        .addToBackStack("name") // name can be null
                        .commit();
            else if(num==5)
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frag_five, Five.class, null)
                        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                        .addToBackStack("name") // name can be null
                        .commit();
            else if(num==1)
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frag_six, Six.class, null)
                        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                        .addToBackStack("name") // name can be null
                        .commit();
        }
    });
```

I'm a beginner, I tried to make this simple dice app, created 6 fragments and in each fragment included an imageview that would display the image for every turn of dice....After compiling the code, I am getting errors stating " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0800c4 (com.example.rollingdice:id/frag_three) for fragment Three{cff507d}" and the app is crashing adruptly.

Comment: please check this if it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id

Comment: Can you add the exception stack trace?

Comment: It occurred on that on click method